# Solving a linear equation in an abstract vector space

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have five abstract vectors a1,a2,a3,a4 and a5  that yield four other objects through abstract addition

```
w1 = a1 + a2;
w2 = a2 + a3;
w3 = a3 + a4;
w4 = a4 + a5;
```

and I want to solve the following equation:

```
 Solve[a*w1 + b*w2 + c*w3 + d*w4 == a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5, {a, b, c, d}]
```

Unfortunately, *Mathematica* gives me the result:

```
{{d -> -((a (a1 + a2))/(a4 + a5)) - (-a1 - a2 - a3 + a4 + a5)/(
a4 + a5) - ((a2 + a3) b)/(a4 + a5) - ((a3 + a4) c)/(a4 + a5)}}
```

How can I tell *Mathematica* that I don't want a1,a2,a3,a4 and a5 in the denominator? In my case these are abstract vectors and thus should not appear in the denominator.

Comment: `Solve[Thread[Last[CoefficientArrays[a*w1 + b*w2 + c*w3 + d*w4 == a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]] == 0], {a, b, c, d}]` says that there are no solutions.

Comment: Try defining `w1 = {w1x, w1y}` and likewise for all vectors.

Comment: `Solve` only handles variables that are integers, reals, or complex. The documentation makes this very clear. To use `Solve` you will have to convert your equation into a system of linear equations in with a known number of variables -- i.e., a vector space of explicitly specified dimension. Solving in abstract vectors spaces is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) is what you want.  It shows that there is no linear combination of the w's that yields the particular linear combination of the a's, assuming they're independent:

```
Block[{w1 = a1 + a2, w2 = a2 + a3, w3 = a3 + a4, w4 = a4 + a5},
 SolveAlways[
  a*w1 + b*w2 + c*w3 + d*w4 == a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5,
  {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]
 ]
(*  {}  *)
```

But a slight change yields a result:

```
Block[{w1 = a1 + a2, w2 = a2 + a3, w3 = a3 + a4, w4 = a4 + a5},
 SolveAlways[
  a*w1 + b*w2 + c*w3 + d*w4 == a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - 2 a5,
  {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]
 ]
(*  {{a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 1, d -> -2}}  *)
```

(The w's will span only a 4-dimensional subspace of the 5-dimensional space spanned by the a's.)